# R: how to calculate fraction of empty rows in all columns of a large matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, sum, col

I'm working with single-nuclei rna sequencing and I made a matrix of a subset of genes across all features that shows the counts per gene for each of them. I want to calculate the proportion of genes that are expressed in each feature but can't get my code to return the right result. This is separate from the number of counts per feature which I calculated with colSums already.

Genes that aren't expressed have a "." value, so I want to count how many of those there in each column, calculate it as a fraction of the total number of genes, and use (1-fraction) to find the proportion of genes expressed for each feature.

What should I use for this counting?

Code that I have tried that doesn't quite work (where counts.fc2 is my matrix):

```
marker <- c('.')
Matrix::colSums(counts.fc2@assays$RNA@counts[markers, ])
```

And

```
na.counts <- counts.fc2[grep(".", counts.fc2), ]
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit: as requested, this is an example of what the matrix looks like (column headers are feature no, eg: CATACTTAGAGTACCG-1:

```
ppn     . 0.8982865 . . .      
ocn     . . . . .         
CheB53a 3.2424953 . . . .        
CG5762  . . . . 0.8982865 
srp     . 2.698674 . . . .

fraction 0.2 0.4 0 0 0.2
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample of your matrix and your expected output?

Comment: @LMc, I just edited the main post.

Comment: Hi! Maybe your issue is using having `.` as a marker. When used in regex, `.` is a special character that matches any character, you need to escape it to use it as is. What's your output using `grep`? What happens if you try `na.counts <- counts.fc2[grep("\\.", counts.fc2), ]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1)
m <- replicate(15, sample(c(letters, "."), 20, replace = T))

colMeans(m != ".")
[1] 0.95 1.00 0.95 1.00 0.95 0.95 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.90 1.00 1.00 0.95 0.95 0.95
```

You can test which elements of your matrix are not `.` using the comparison operator `!=`. `m != "."` will output a boolean matrix that is `FALSE` for the elements that are `.` and `TRUE` otherwise. `colMeans` will return the proportion of each column that is `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but I get an error message that I don't understand:                                     > colMeans(counts.fc2 != ".")
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'colMeans': not-yet-implemented method for !=(<dgCMatrix>, <character>).
 ->>  Ask the package authors to implement the missing feature.